# DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400] Exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a Flutter Restful web application and the web api backend as asp.net core. When i try to send the form data using post request it is throwing this error

> DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400] Exception

**Code**

```
onPressed: () async {
 String email_value = emailController.text;
 String password_value = passController.text;
 String fullname_value = fullnameController.text;
 var repassword_value = repassController.text;
 print("$email_value");
 if (password_value == repassword_value) {
 try{
 Dio dio = Dio();
 var body = jsonEncode(
  {
    'FullName': '$fullname_value',
    'Email': '$email_value',
    'Password': '$password_value'
  }
 );
 print("Body" + body);
 Response response = await dio.post("http://iamtv.chainuniverse.com/api/Accounts/Register",
  data: body,
  options: Options(
    contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
  )
 );
 var jsonData = json.decode(response.data);
 print(jsonData);
 if (response.statusCode > 200 &&
    response.statusCode < 250) {
  print("Sucess");
  await loginAction();
  print("Registered");
 }
 else{
  print(jsonData);
 }
```

But when i send data manually without using textcontroller Text it works. Please help me to fix this

Working perfectly in POSTMAN
[image: t]

Comment: Check for URL in browser first if it working or not?

Comment: Its working perfectly

Comment: Your body object is not compatible with the model in your backend. Check them they should be the same

Comment: No its working correctly

Comment: change json.decode to encode like `var jsonData = json.encode(response.data)` and if condition as `` if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 250)`` . Also, this may not problem as I tested your code and I am getting successful response and statuscode 200.

Comment: @Raj How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late answer, may help you.

I was getting same error with `Dio` and `form-data`. It worked! after adding `contentType`

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "image-param-name": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    imageFile.path,
    filename: fileName,
    contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg"), //add this
  ),
});
```

complete code

```
var dio = Dio();
String fileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "image-param-name": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    imageFile.path,
    filename: fileName,
    contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg"), //add this
  ),
});

var response = await dio.post(
  "url",
  data: formData,
  options: Options(
    headers: {
      "Authorization": auth-token
    },
  ),
  onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
    debugPrint("sent${sent.toString()}" + " total${total.toString()}");
  },
).whenComplete(() {
  debugPrint("complete:");
}).catchError((onError) {
  debugPrint("error:${onError.toString()}");
});
```

Comment: where is the MediaType class from ? I tried to do so but I couldn't import MedaType class... Is it from dio package ?

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055016/16328296) we have to import http parser.

```
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue though from my end it was about the format I was

Check your format to ensure it aligns with this

```
 FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'image': MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    imageBytes,
    filename: 'image.jpg',
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'), // Adjust content type if necessary
  ),
  'key1': 'value1', // Additional data
  'key2': 'value2', // Additional data
});
```