# Flutter: App is stuck on white screen loading

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I tried to run and App in Android Studio, but he is stocking in loading white screen page.

Any solution? I will apretiate any help, thanks!

PD: The app is https://codecanyon.net/item/masterstudy-lms-mobile-app-flutter-ios-android/27103832

Screenshot of how is showing in the celphone: https://prnt.sc/SHtC2-4IIpwK

```
has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                       ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/web_selection_manager.dart:119:24: Warning: Operand of
null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!
                       ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:138:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
                           ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:140:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!
                         ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:141:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
                         ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:143:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
                       ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:193:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
                         ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:195:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
                       ^
/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/overlay_support-1.2.1/lib/src/overlay_entry.dart:101:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has
type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        WidgetsBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback((_) => animateRemove());
                       ^
Syncing files to device 2109119DG...                               551ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

An Observatory debugger and profiler on 2109119DG is available at: http://127.0.0.1:56868/txVLacBS3yA=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on 2109119DG is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:56868/txVLacBS3yA=/
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend(32512): Status Code: 200
I/flutter (32512): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter (32512): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404]
I/flutter (32512): Source stack:
I/flutter (32512): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
I/flutter (32512): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
I/flutter (32512): #2      DioMixin.get (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:61:12)
I/flutter (32512): #3      SplashWidgetState.getAppSettingColor (package:masterstudy_app/ui/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart:52:37)
I/flutter (32512): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (32512): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:643:7)
I/flutter (32512): #1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
I/flutter (32512): #2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
I/flutter (32512): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
I/flutter (32512): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
I/flutter (32512): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
I/flutter (32512): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
I/flutter (32512): #7      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
I/flutter (32512): #8      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5)
I/flutter (32512): #9      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:616:45)
I/flutter (32512): #10     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
I/flutter (32512): #11     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
I/flutter (32512): #12     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
I/flutter (32512): #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
I/flutter (32512): #14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/fu
I/flutter (32512): ----------------------------------------------------
V/MiuiFrameworkFactory(32512): get AllImpl object = android.common.MiuiFrameworkFactoryImpl@b406fd8
W/MirrorManager(32512): this model don't Support
D/ForceDarkHelper(32512): onAppDarkModeChanged updateForceDarkMode: true
D/AnrScout(32512): AppScoutStateMachine created
D/FrameIndicator(32512): support status: 1 0x6f0ac5d018 0x6f0ac5d4c4
D/FrameIndicator(32512): support status: 1 0x6f0ac5d018 0x6f0ac5d4c4
```

Comment: Unfortunately not much of the info provided is helpful. Can you share the code of the application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055016/11898242 check if this is the issue

Comment: @Apealed The complete code added.

Answer (score 0):

I think 404 comes from your server request so cross-check whether your backend server responds perfectly or not via the postman.

Comment: I figure that in my project the flutter flags are not showing, can be this the problem? https://prnt.sc/VSDmQgJLO-uX   https://prnt.sc/axm231EtTxpv

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you trying to say